# Laravel response 404 in all static files for generated URL

Tags: php, laravel-7

I'm using Laravel 7, PHP 7.4 running on docker with the following config:

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y autoconf pkg-config libssl-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-install bcmath sockets
RUN apt-get install -y libpq-dev 

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php \
        && mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/ \
        && ln -s /usr/local/bin/composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER 1

WORKDIR /website

ENTRYPOINT ["php", "-S", "0.0.0.0:8080", "-t", "/website"]
```

I stored all the assets in the directory: `public/assets`

All URL responses are `404 Not Found` like the following image:

[image]

I generated the URL in the view with the following code:

```html
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ url('assets/images/favicon.ico') }}">
```

- What is missing? Should I do some specific config?

Comment: Why your static files request 8050 port? Maybe you need 8080

Comment: does `asset( )` method not working too ? https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-asset

Comment: I also tried `asset()` method but got the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel applications start at `index.php` inside public folder.

Your built-in PHP Server listening now `/website` folder but it must listen `/website/public` folder.

Now you may access images at this address: `http://0.0.0.0:8080/public/assets/images/favicon.ico` with your wrong entrypoint configuration.

This configuration has vulnerabilities:

- Makes all application folders are accesible for public when it deployed in production. (app/bootstrap/storage/resources etc. folders...)
- And you can only access your routes with /public prefix because you must go public/index.php for starting Laravel.

**So, your entrypoint must be:**
`ENTRYPOINT ["php", "-S", "0.0.0.0:8080", "-t", "/website/public"]`

Answer (score -1):

Need more info.

Check the owner/group of the folder/files.
That is a usual problem when using docker.

Comment: I have a similar project in similar docker config, running on laravel 5.4 and It works perfect, I checked the permissions and are the following: `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Jun  8 17:47 favicon.ico` is they're something specific it should be?